# I'm trying to sort my array of objects but its not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to sort my array of objects but its not working. Can someone see why its not working?

```
    function App(){
      let products = [
        {
          name: "LED",
          price: 50000,
          status: true,
          image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
        },
        {
          name: "Bike",
          price: 40000,
          status: false,
          image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
        },
        {
          name: "Mobile",
          price: 60000,
          status: true,
          image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
        },
        {
          name: "Apple Watch",
          price: 6000,
          status: true,
          image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
        }
      ];
    
      return (
        <div>
    
          <ul>
            {
              products.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is the error I'm getting.
**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, price, status, image}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. Plain objects can't be rendered. Figure out how you want the objects to display.

Comment: What are you trying to render? The names of each item? If so, you need to use `.map()` on your array _of objects_ and return an element that can be rendered such as JSX

Comment: I want to sort my objects with respect to price. Just like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values

Comment: It's work but you can`t render plain object. Use map function to create array of JSX elements  ```products.sort(...).map(item=><div>{item.name}:{item.price}</div>```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

let products = [
  {
    name: "LED",
    price: 50000,
    status: true,
    image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
  },

  {
    name: "Bike",
    price: 40000,
    status: false,
    image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Mobile",
    price: 60000,
    status: true,
    image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Apple Watch",
    price: 6000,
    status: true,
    image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png"
  }
];

function App() {
  const memoizedProducts = useMemo(
    () =>
      products.sort((a, b) => {
        const priceA = parseFloat(a.price);
        const priceB = parseFloat(b.price);

        if (priceA < priceB) return -1;
        if (priceA > priceB) return 1;

        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {memoizedProducts.map(({ name, price }, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {name} - {price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function App() {
  let products = [
    {
      name: "LED",
      price: 50000,
      status: true,
      image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png",
    },
    {
      name: "Bike",
      price: 40000,
      status: false,
      image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png",
    },
    {
      name: "Mobile",
      price: 60000,
      status: true,
      image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png",
    },
    {
      name: "Apple Watch",
      price: 6000,
      status: true,
      image: "images/products/Krunch-Combo-kfc.png",
    },
  ];

  const sortedProducts = products.sort(
    (productA, productB) =>
      parseFloat(productA.price) - parseFloat(productB.price)
  );

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ul>{JSON.stringify(sortedProducts)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In order to render the products in `jsx` in the `DOM` use the higher order array function `map`.

**Good luck let me know if this is what you was looking for**